# Android SQLite QUERI to retrieve data from Table A if the data is in Table B too

Tags: android, sqlite

In an Android application and SQLite, there are 2 tables as following:

***Table A is composed of the following 4 columns:***

```
ID1,ID2,DATA1,DATA2: 

ID1   ID2   DATA1   DATA2 
A     E     D1      D4
B     F     D2      D5
C     G     D3      D6
D     H     D4      D7
```

***Table B is composed of the following 3 columns:***

```
ID1,ID2,DATA3: 

ID1   ID2   DATA3 
A     E     Y
B     F     N
C     G     Y
D     H     N
```

***I need a QUERI to result in the following data:***

```
ID1   ID2   DATA1   DATA2 
A     E     D1      D4
C     G     D3      D6
```

In other words, I need all data in Table A where:

***1 - ID1 and ID2 are available in Table B

2 - DATA3 for that ID1 and ID2 would be "Y" in the Table B***

Comment: There is no DATA3 column in your result.

Comment: No, there is no need for DATA3 colomn in the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA A 
INNER JOIN TABLEB B 
ON A.ID1 = B.ID1 AND A.ID2 = B.ID2 
WHERE B.DATA3 = 'Y'
```

Comment: It works fine for small databases but when I increase the records I have the following issue: Window is full: requested allocation 372 bytes, free space 106 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes